# How can I mix Image with a Video stream from USB capture device using DirectShowLib in C#

Tags: c#, .net, directx, directshow

I'm able to show  a video stream in a window. I'm using DirectShow VideoMixingRenderer9 in C#. I have created an Image with sometext in it. Now, how can I mix this image with the video stream so that both video stream and text is shown in the capture window. I tried with ISampleGrabber filter but it doesn't work with all video device and capture screan only shows the text with black background but no video stream. So I don't want to use ISampleGrabber filter.

Comment: This seams to be a similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699024/showing-a-semi-transparent-image-object-over-an-ivideowindow-in-c-sharp-using-di

Answer (score 0):

IVMRMixerBitmap9 interface should help you, which is implemented by the VMR. This is the link to MSDN:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390451(v=vs.85).aspx][1]

The bitmap needs to have alpha values so that it can be blended with the rendered video.

Comment: @Shomrat Shomrat : If this helped you, would you please accept the answer?